# Java game sever/client multiple instances

Tags: java, server, client, game-engine, multiplayer

I have working on a java game where I have implemented a server and client class to allow for multiplayer. My question is how do identify my servers so my clients know which game they want to join.

Example:
I start a game and run it as a server. My 2 friends start the game as clients and join my game. If there is any other group of people that want to start there own game, when they start up a game as a server how to the other players know which server to join. Current state everyone joins the same server.

Comment: Just allow clients to connect to a different IP and port.

Answer (score 0):

You need organize your server like this:
Zone A:
    Room 1
    Room 2
Zone B:
    Room 1
    Room 2

when your users join to a zone or a room, you can broadcast message to them

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more? I want each play to have the ability to host there own game (be the server) and allow the other players (clients) to choose which game(server) they want to join.

Comment: ok let's say you have 8 players, you can organize like this:

`
Server
    + ZoneA
        + Room1
        + Room2
`

Comment: `
1. flow to make an user become a room master:

    1.1 User connect to server
    1.1.1 Server response connect success
    /*
        Do some works like: handshake, login
    */
    1.2 User send command join zone (ZoneA)
`

Comment: `
    1.2.1 Server response ZoneA's information
    1.3. User send command join room (Room1)
    1.3.1 Server response Room1's information
    1.4 User send command 'become_a_master'
    1.5.1 Server response command 'become_a_master' with status 'success'
`

Comment: `
2 flow to make an user become a player
    2.1 User connect to server
    2.1.1 Server response connect success
    /*
        Do some works like: handshake, login
    */
`

Comment: `
    2.2 User send command join zone (ZoneA)
    2.2.1 Server response ZoneA's information
    2.3. User send command join room (Room1)
    2.3.1 Server response Room1's information and now the user has been a player
`